# D flip flop data extraction

Tags: data, flipflop, computer-architecture

How do you get the data out of a d flip flop?  On [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#D_flip-flop) it says that if the clock is non-rising then it ouputs Q.  Isn't the clock always non-rising if it's not changing the data?  If it is, then the data is constantly being output every second, even when not asked for it...

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you have heard its alternate name, "transparent data latch".

Comment: @JGord D flip-flop is not the same thing as D latch

Comment: @W5V0 Hah, thats true... depends what book you're reading. My FPGA book had latches as level triggered and flip-flops as edge triggered. On the other hand my VLSI book had flip-flops and latches equivalent and called edge triggered devices registers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D flip flops are simply recording the state of something (input D) when an event happens (the rising edge of the clock), and presenting that recorded value at output Q.

Say you have a car and one of two paint cans (white or black) next to it. The car "outputs" the color it was last painted. A "painting event" is picking up that paint can and painting the car with it. The car then "outputs" the new color, until a new paint can is presented and you have a new "painting event".

You don't ask the car to output it's color, it just does. The voltage output Q of the flip flop is the same way (assuming there's power and it's functioning properly).

Answer (score 3):

It just means that Q only changes (to D) on the rising (or falling in some FFs) edge. At all other times it will remain in the state clocked from the last rising (or falling) edge, even if D changes.

So you can think of it as capturing the value of D at specfic moments in time (e.g. on the rising clock edge), and storing this value until the next rising edge (or replace "rising" with "falling" for a negative edge triggered FF)

This is assuming a D flip flop as linked to in the question.